# How to change legend values on ggplot pie chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have built this particular table in R to build a pie chart using the ggplot package.

```
column,value,proportion,ypos,end,start,middle,hjust,vjust,legend
Urban,268053,97.78067170794165,48.890335853970825,6.143740798014896,0,3.071870399007448,0,1,Urban - 97.78 %
Rural,1296,0.4727563225686427,98.01704986922597,6.173444953813291,6.143740798014896,6.158592875914094,1,0,Rural - 0.47 %
Suburban,4788,1.746571969489708,99.12671401525515,6.283185307179586,6.173444953813291,6.228315130496439,1,0,Suburban - 1.75 %
```

However, I want all values in the legend column and NOT the column column to be printed in the legend because the legend variables are just too cramped together if I decide to label them in the pie chart. I also would like to change the legend title.

[image]

Below is the code I have used to build this graph.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
library(readxl)

demographics <- read_csv("C:\\path to file\\demographics.csv")

ggplot(demographics) + 
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0, r = 1,
                   start = start, end = end, fill = column)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1.5, 1.4),  # Adjust so labels are not cut off
                     name = "", breaks = NULL, labels = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 1),      # Adjust so labels are not cut off
                     name = "", breaks = NULL, labels = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Community Type", labels = c(legend)) +
  ggtitle("Percentage of Population by Type of Community")
```

Can anybody assist me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
library(readxl)
library(ggforce)

ggplot(demographics) + 
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0, r = 1,
                   start = start, end = end, fill = legend)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1.5, 1.4),  # Adjust so labels are not cut off
                     name = "", breaks = NULL, labels = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 1),      # Adjust so labels are not cut off
                     name = "", breaks = NULL, labels = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Community Type", labels = c(legend)) +
  ggtitle("Percentage of Population by Type of Community")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="New Legend Title"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Works for me! Thank you so much.